# python set of objects with custom hash behavior

Tags: python, hash, set

I would like to use a set to manage a collection of 'myItem' instances. The myItem class has its own hash function.
The hash of these items is based on some but not all of the data in each item, for simplicity in the example below the 'data' is dictionary r. The hash takes into account 2 keys, hk1 and hk2, and there is a third key 'sad' that is not considered in the hash calculation.

```
class myItem():

    def __init__(self, r):
        # r is a dict holding information about the instance
        # of course r has to have certain keys...
        self.r = r

    def __hash__(self):
        """Override the default hash behavior"""
        return hash(tuple(sorted([self.r['hk1'],self.r['hk2']])))

    def __eq__(self,other):
        """checking equality"""
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__hash__() == other.__hash__()
        return NotImplemented

    def __ne__(self, other):
        """checking inequality"""
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return not self.__eq__(other)
        return NotImplemented

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.r)
```

The expected behavior is confirmed by the short unit test below.

```
class testMySet(unittest.TestCase):

    def testMyItemstuff(self):

        m1 = myItem({'hk1':'val1', 'hk2': 100, 'sad': 'other stuff'})
        m2 = myItem({'hk1': 'val1', 'hk2': 100, 'sad': 'different other stuff'})

        self.assertEqual(m1, m2)
        self.assertNotEqual(m1.r['sad'], m2.r['sad'])

        s = { m1 }
        # add m2 to s
        s.add(m2)
        # same hash, m2 is not added
        self.assertEqual(len(s), 1)
        # set contains the original object, not the last one added
        self.assertNotEqual(s.pop().r['sad'], 'different other stuff')
```

My question is, how can I modify the behavior such that adding a new object whose hash coincides with an existing one ends up replacing the original one, with minimal performance impact?

Comment: `return self.__hash__() == other.__hash__()` - that is not a safe way to implement equality comparison.

Comment: Are you aware that hash collision is a thing? You seem to be expecting hash values to be enough to perfectly distinguish objects.

Comment: Given on the way you've set up your class, replacing your `set` with a `dict` would work (and changing `add`, etc.), but the general approach still seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether defining your hash that way makes sense for your application is really for you to decide, but it does seem unlikely.

In any case, I can think of two options that will be "as fast as" a set -- O(1) instead of O(n) -- and their speed depends on implementing a hash function as you describe:

First, boil down your class and create instances:

```
class Item():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.a)

    def __eq__(self,other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            # Ignoring .b attribute
            return self.a == other.a
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Item(%s, %s)" % (self.a, self.b)

i1 = Item(1,2)
i2 = Item(3,4)
i3 = Item(1,5)


print(i1 == i2)             # False (.a's don't match)
print(i1 == i3)             # True  (.a's match)
```

**Method 1: dict values**

```
# Using a dict
updating_set = {}
updating_set[i1] = i1       # .values(): [Item(1, 2)]
updating_set[i2] = i2       # .values(): [Item(1, 2), Item(3, 4)]
updating_set[i3] = i3       # .values(): [Item(1, 5), Item(3, 4)]

print(list(updating_set.values()))
# [Item(1, 5), Item(3, 4)]
```

**Method 2: Using a set subclass**

```
# Using a set subclass
class UpdatingSet(set):
    def add(self, item):
        if item in self: super().remove(item)
        super().add(item)

uset = UpdatingSet()
uset.add(i1)                # UpdatingSet({Item(1, 2)})
uset.add(i2)                # UpdatingSet({Item(1, 2), Item(3, 4)})
uset.add(i3)                # UpdatingSet({Item(1, 5), Item(3, 4)})
```

**Bonus Method 3: Not requiring a special hash function**

```
class NewItem():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Item(%s, %s)" % (self.a, self.b)

class ItemSet():
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = {}

    def add(self, item):
        item_hash = item.a
        self.items[item_hash] = item

    def values(self):
        return self.items.values()

i1 = NewItem(1,2)
i2 = NewItem(3,4)
i3 = NewItem(1,5)

iset = ItemSet()
iset.add(i1)                # .values(): [Item(1, 2)]
iset.add(i2)                # .values(): [Item(1, 2), Item(3, 4)]
iset.add(i3)                # .values(): [Item(1, 5), Item(3, 4)]

print(list(iset.values()))  # [Item(1, 5), Item(3, 4)]
```

This third approach doesn't require you to implement **hash** (which could cause unexpected side effects, but mimics the hashing process inside `ItemSet.add()`, using the "hash function" as the dictionary key.

This is probably your best bet, unless you *really* want to implement hash and know the extent of the effects of that decision.

Comment: Please bear with me and thanks to all for pointing my unsafe use of hash. Allow me to check my understanding of hash: a nonlinear function that computes a numeric value from non mutable input. There is a chance that two different inputs, 'a' in @jedwards example could result in the same hash value, am I on the right track?

Comment: @AdrianC Yes that's what a hash general is. But for the custom implementation `__hash__` in Python you can return really anything. Whether it makes sense is up to you. Hash collisions can always happen [even for sophisticated algorithms](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/02/watershed-sha1-collision-just-broke-the-webkit-repository-others-may-follow). The point of `__eq__` is to really distinguish objects (even, or especially, for hash collisions). This is what e.g. `dict` or `set` check when the hashes are the same. They want to assess whether the objects are really the same.

Comment: Accepting @jedwards' answer: I decided to go for the third "bonus" solution because I don't have a real need to monkey around with python's hashes. Creating the dict keys of the store using my own 'hashing rules' suffices.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your custom `set` derivative:

```
class CustomSet(set):
    def add(self, item):
        self.discard(item)
        super().add(item)
```

Note that this relies on the fact that, as you showed in your example, two items compare equal if and only if their hashes compare equal.

This is not how the built-in hash based containers are intended to be used though. They use hashes for quick lookups and in case of collisions they use the equality comparison to resolve the clash (i.e. check if it's true equality).

If `__eq__` depends on something else than the hash, then you need to keep track of the hashes as well (in form of a `dict` for example):

```
class CustomSet(set):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._hashes = {}

    def add(self, item):
        self.discard(self._hashes.get(hash(item)))
        self._hashes[hash(item)] = item
        super().add(item)

    # Similarly implement the following methods to update self._hashes:
    #   * clear
    #   * discard
    #   * pop
    #   * remove
```

Comment: your answer is useful and I tried a version of it, however I adopted the solution above since I don't need to interfere with python's hashes. My class originally overrid __eq__ in part due to being able to use the == operator but I since decided to just have a method other than __eq__ to check equality from the perspective of my hash, and let the interpreter do its thing.