# How to ignore function arguments with cachetools ttl_cache

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching

I'm exploiting the [cachetools](https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#) `@ttl_cache` decorator (not `@cached`). I need to ignore some params in the cache key. E.g,.

```
@ttl_cache(maxsize=1024, ttl=600)
def my_func(foo, ignore_bar, ignore_baz):
    # do stuff
```

Working that way, I get this:

```
>>> my_func("foo", "ignore_bar", "ignore_baz")         # cache miss
>>> my_func("foo", "ignore_bar", "ignore_baz")         # cache hit
>>> my_func("foo", "ignore_bar_bar", "ignore_baz_baz") # cache miss!
```

What I need:

```
>>> my_func("foo", "ignore_bar", "ignore_baz")         # cache miss
>>> my_func("foo", "ignore_bar", "ignore_baz")         # cache hit
>>> my_func("foo", "ignore_bar_bar", "ignore_baz_baz") # cache hit!!!!!
```

Is there a way to get that using `@ttl_cache`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used cachetools, but I've looked at the docs out of interest. Apparently, there's no built-in way. If you *really* need this functionality, I can suggest a hack like the following:

```py
class PackedArgs(tuple):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self[0])

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self[0] == other[0]
        else:
            return NotImplemented

def pack_args(func):
    def inner(packed_args):
        return func(*packed_args)
    return inner

def unpack_args(func):
    def inner(*args):
        return func(PackedArgs(args))
    return inner

@unpack_args
@ttl_cache(maxsize=1024, ttl=600)
@pack_args
def my_func(foo, ignore_bar, ignore_baz):
    # do stuff
```

Essentially: "pack" your function's arguments to a single tuple-like object that hashes as it's 0th element and causes `@ttl_cache` to behave like you need. Then, "unpack" them to restore the normal interface and avoid actually having to pass this one big argument when calling.

Please note that this is just a (very hacky) concept, I haven't tested this code at all. It probably won't work as is.

By the way, your requirement sounds interesting. You can submit it to cachetools as a feauture request and link this thread. I can imagine it being implemented as something like a `key=` kwarg lambda, similar to builtin `sort`'s.

Comment: Thanx for this suggestion. I'll try that out and I'll let you know my remarks about it.

Comment: Ok, just tried but it didn't work. Theoretically, it should, since the params passed to `@pack_args` do have the same hash. Maybe the `@ttl_cache` is behaving in a different way behind the scenes

Comment: My hashing hack is probably just sloppy, guys [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51014668/python-set-of-objects-with-custom-hash-behavior) seem to also override `__eq__`. You can also check `@ttl_cache`'s source code, if you really need to get this done

Comment: Thanx. I really appreciated the idea behind this workaround.

Comment: Adding `__eq__` seems working! I've just edited your original answer! Let me know if my edit sounds good to you

Comment: Sure, keep it, it makes the answer self-sufficient and more useful if someone else comes across

Answer (score 5):

Well, that's exactly what `@cached` and its custom `key` argument are for, so I wonder why you want to use `@ttl_cache` for this:

```
from cachetools import TTLCache, cached
from cachetools.keys import hashkey

def mykey(foo, ignore_bar, ignore_baz):
    return hashkey(foo)

@cached(cache=TTLCache(maxsize=1024, ttl=600), key=mykey)
def my_func(foo, ignore_bar, ignore_baz):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, the reason is that I need to call `cache_info()` and `cache_clear()` that are not available for the `@cached` decorator (see [here](https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-cachetools.func))

Comment: I see. There's already a feature request for adding these to `@cached`, which would probably be the way to go: https://github.com/tkem/cachetools/issues/131
However, until this gets implemented (which I'm afraid won't happen too soon), there is no "official" way to do this, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. It could be an option using `cache.clear()` with `@cached`, instead of `cache_clear()` with `@ttl_cache`. However, statistics will be lost.

Comment: Right. #131 was already scheduled for v5.0.0, but was deferred due to lack of resources. However, it will definitely be considered for a future release, but don't ask for release dates ;-)

Comment: Ok thank you. In the meanwhile, I'll use this hack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70535619/4820341